# Getting the basename of each subpath in a string

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to `Vue` and `JS` in general. Consider an array of objects and each one of them have a "name" - it's actually some processes/cmds like:

```
/disks/tools/itools/odor/src/bin/lib/script.py -path /disks/tools/itools/ps/char/leno/tool/src/work/dir -i ./report/dir/bin/a -report -id 12345 --name my_/name
```

I wrote the following piece of code which gets this array, iterates through it and adds a short version to each one of them. So for the example above we get:

```
script.py -path dir -i a -report -id 12345 --name my_/name
```

Meaning, each substring that contains a "path" will be converted into a small one. (I think that we can catch all of the cases by looking at the first symbol of the substring - if it's `/` or `./` then we should take the basename).

My code:

```
addShort: function(arr) {
    for (var i of arr) {
        if (i.name) {
            i.fullname = i.name;
            i.name = '';
            var splitedArr = i.fullname.split(' ');
            for (var path of splitedArr) {
                i.name += this.basename(path);
            }
        }
    }
},

basename: function(str) {
    var nStr = str.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    if (newStr) {
       return newStr + ' ';
    }
    return '';
}
```

Due to the fact that I'm new to `Vue` and `JS` I have doubts about this piece of code. I feel like, it could be written cleaner and nicely, secondly, I'm not sure that my regex catches all the needed cases. Also, I noticed that each string has additional unneeded space at the end so I thought to change the `basename` function to be:

```
basename: function(str) {
    var nStr = str.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
    return newStr | '';
}
```

And add space to `i.name += this.basename(path);` so it will be something like: `i.name += this.basename(path).' ';` . But then it will keep the additional space at the end - is there a way to if we entered the last iteration of the loop so we won't add the space?

Sorry for making you waste time on my doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter way:

```es6
i.name = i.fullname
  .split(/\s+/)
  .map(arg => this.basename(arg))
  .join(' ');
```

Also the `basename` function can just be shortened to:

```es6
basename(str) {
  // Will take the basename of strings that start in a / or ./ only
  return str.replace(/^\.?\/.*[\\\/]/, '');
}
```

> I think that we can catch all of the cases by looking at the first symbol of the substring - if it's `/` or `./` then we should take the basename

Keep in mind relative paths can be like this too:

```
path/to/file.txt
```

Also be careful that you're not creating the `i.fullname` property (it should already exist in the `i` object) otherwise it won't be reactive (if you're rendering it in the template).

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to add in that unit testing is the main way I put myself at ease when I'm working in new territory. Throw in some simple unit tests, it doesn't have to be anything fancy that will help you say definitively that the functions you wrote work as expected. There are several phenomenal unit testing frameworks for js (i.e. Jest or Jasmine).

In addition, if you are having some difficulty getting your regex to work for every case, I'd recommend [this regex site](https://regex101.com/) because of its quick reference panel in the bottom left that describes exactly what regex character options you can choose from.